# como mover texto de un li en css?

Tags: css3

tengo un texto dentro de un li y quiero moverlo pero no quiero alinearlo justo al centro, es un poquito antes del centro, quisiera mover el texto como si lo moviera con position relative pero cuando uso position relative se mueve el contenedor no el texto.
¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtar por agregra una padding-right en tu css externo o incrustarlo dentro de la etiqueta li de la siguiente forma:

```
<li style='padding-right: 10px;'>texto a mover</li>
```

Si esto no te funciona el motivo puede ser que las propiedades del css estén chocando entre sí, prueba agregar un atributo !important para la propiedad padding-right, así:

```
<li style='padding-right: 10px !important;'>texto a mover</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

encierra el texto dentro de un div  ej:

```
  <li> <div id="movimiento">   texto a mover   </div ></li >
```

y con css agregas un padding-rigth y empiezas a "Jugar" con el porcentaje que necesites hasta q logres la posicion deseada

```
 .moviemiento{

 padding-riht : 70%;
  }
```